# Android appcompact doesn't show copy action from Contextual Action Bar for text selection

Tags: android, android-webview, android-appcompat

I faced with the weird issue. 
When I use android holo theme as default theme, and then selecting text on webview, the contextual action bar show correctly.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">   
</style>
```

[image]

But when I use app compact holo theme, the select all and copy action are gone.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">   
</style>
```

[image]

Where is my problem? My app supports android devices 4.0+

Comment: If you are using App compact theme then you must use `app:showAsAction="always"` instead of `android:showAsAction="always"` for your menu item and add xml schema for that  `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto`.

Comment: @PiyushGupta well, actually, I don't use any custom option menu or custom CAB, this is the default behavior on web view selection (I mean I don't override onCreateOptionMenu or something like that), test on several samsung devices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in your menu.xml file you use atribute `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"` for not app commpat theme. 
Please change `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"` to `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` and should work

Example

For this style

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
```

works below menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/pase"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_paste_mtrl_am_alpha"
       //look here is a different
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/copy"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          android:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

For this style

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

works below menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/pase"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_paste_mtrl_am_alpha"
       //look here is a different
          app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/copy"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

Additionally if you use `Theme.AppCompat.Light` you should use ActivityActionBar in your code.

Comment: well, actually, I don't use any custom option menu or custom CAB, this is the default behavior on web view selection (I mean I don't override onCreateOptionMenu or something like that), test on several samsung devices

Comment: I don't understand what do you exactly mean.  How do you inflate your menu? If you want to create your own menu you have to override onCreateOptionMenu method.

Comment: I don't use option menu. The layout has a webview, a long press on webview will fire a Contextual action bar, and that's it. I mean all of them are default behavior of webview, no customize. As this site http://android-ed.blogspot.com/2012/10/copy-text-in-webview-in-android-23-and.html?m=1 mention: Copy functionality in a WebView is available by default in Android 3.0 and above

Comment: So reason is the same as in the example above, some one who implement action bar for copy paste has to use attribute from appCommpat.

Comment: But I tested your issue on Nexus 5 And everything works good, These menus look different but all options are visible.

Comment: Is recommended to use app compat components because, there are already fixed many of known issue from standard Android Api

Comment: I don't get your idea. I use app compact without option menu, but this problem occur on my samsung devices. How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you extends Activity or ActionBarActivity? If Activity try to change to ActionBarActivity

Comment: Yup, extend ActionBarActivity can solve this problem. My bad.

Comment: That's great I'm glad that I could help you